# How to combine 2 different variable types into 1 javascript code

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser, device

I currently got 2 working scripts for 2 different purposes:
1) is an auto redirect script basing on browser language
2) is a script who sends visitors to specific pages basing on device in use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
window.onload=function(){
if (language.indexOf('fr') > -1) {
document.location.href = 'mysite.com/french';
} else {
document.location.href = 'mysite.com/intl'; }}</script>


<script>function DeviceDirection()
{ if( 
/nokia/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || 
/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) 
{ window.open('mysite.com/android_and_nokia_devices'); }else{ window.open('mysite.com/all_devices'); } }</script>
```

I need to combine these 2 functions into 1 script, directing visitors who click a certain button into one page dedicated to French users using Android only, while all others should go to another general page.

I've tried to type the following code, and edited it in several ways, but doesn't work. Can you help me making it correct? Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
window.open=function FrenchAndroid(){
if (
/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
language.indexOf('fr') > -1) )
{ window.open('mysite.com/android_devices_for_french_visitors/');
}else{
window.open('mysite.com/all_other_languages_and_devices'); } }
</script>
```

Please help me with the building of this one here above.

Comment: Your `if` should use `&&` instead of `||` because you want both conditions to met, that the user is using an android device and is indeed a french visitor

Comment: You're overwriting the `window.open` function then you actually call `window.open()` in your new function. This leads to infinite recursion. Do you want the page to open in a new window/tab or do you want it to load in the current tab? `window.open()` opens a new window/tab and `location.href = ` loads the page in the current tab.

Comment: Thx @Lixus for the hint.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I'd like to open in a new tab through window.open function, but yeah, I typed it twice and can't actually figure out which part is needed and which should be deleted or edited :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code snippet is what you need:

```
function isFrenchAndroid() {
    var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    var isAndroid = /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var isFrench = language.indexOf('fr') !== -1;

    return isFrench && isAndroid;
}

var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (isFrenchAndroid()) {
        window.open('https://www.google.fr');
    } else {
        window.open('https://www.google.com');
    }
});
```

The function `isFrenchAndroid` returns `true` if the device is running Android and the language of the browser is french. Then a click event is attached to the button and after checking a new window is open. You can see a running example in this [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/jozeduliwe/edit?html,js,output).

If you don't want to open a new window, I recommend using `window.location.href = 'https://www.google.fr'` instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it isn't working. When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you show your final code? If you have an Ad Blocker installed it's possible that is blocking the `window.open`. Please, try my code in https://jsbin.com/jozeduliwe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @DanielleFiorucci So, you're not actually using a `button`, you're using an `h5` and `img`. Why is that?

Comment: You have an error in your JavaScript. Here is the link with the correct code https://jsbin.com/pokomuyaki/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Now it works amazingly.
Thank you so much for your priceless help.
Really appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood what you're trying to accomplish, this should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var language = navigator.language && navigator.userLanguage;
  function openPage() {
    if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && language.indexOf('fr') > -1)) {
      window.open('mysite.com/android_devices_for_french_visitors/');
    } else {
      window.open('mysite.com/all_other_languages_and_devices');
    } 
  }
</script>
```

Now you just have to invoke `openPage()` where you want it to happen.
For example, if you want it to run when a button is clicked, add an event listener that invokes `openPage` on the button:

`buttonElement.addEventListener("click", openPage);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it isn't working. When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: @DanielleFiorucci I just rewrote the code you were having trouble with to make it work. But if you want the code to run when you click a button you have to add an event listener to the button that invokes `openPage`. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Still not working. Am I making it wrong or?
Here is my test: https://jsbin.com/tagedapoki/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @DanielleFiorucci Yes, you're still missing code that ties it all together. `buttonElement` needs to be defined as a reference to the element you're using as a button. There are different ways of doing this with methods such as `document.getElementById()`, `document.getElementsByTagName()`, `document.querySelector()` etc. Read up on those methods and how to use them.